# Icinga2 check_by_ssh plugin returns 255 without running the command

Tags: bash, monitoring, icinga2

I'm configuring a **Icinga2** server and want it to run local scripts on external machines using the **check_by_ssh** plugin, and I encountered a strange issue. I've searched for an answer for few hours, but no luck.

My command object looks as follows:

```
object CheckCommand "check_procs" {
        import "by_ssh"
        vars.by_ssh_logname = "root"
        vars.by_ssh_port = "22"
        vars.by_ssh_command = "/tmp/test.sh"
        vars.by_ssh_identity = "/etc/icinga2/conf.d/services/id_rsa.pub"
        vars.by_ssh_ipv4 = "true"
        vars.by_ssh_quiet = "true"
}
```

The content of `test.sh` is simply `exit 0`. I have a trust between my Icinga box and the remote machine I'm running the command at.

When I'm executing the command thru shell, it works

```
[root@icinga ~]# ssh root@10.10.10.1 -C "/tmp/test.sh"
[root@icinga ~]# echo $?
0
```

But when it is executed by the server, I see on my **Icingaweb2** this output:

> UNKNOWN - check_by_ssh: Remote command '/tmp/test.sh' returned status 255

Now I have added a `touch success` to `test.sh` script, in order to see if it is executed at all - but it seems it doesn't. That means when Icinga executes my script, it fails before even executing it.

Any clues what can it be? There are no many examples online either of `check_by_ssh` with Icinga2.

**NOTE:** Icinga uses root user to identify with the remote server. I know this is not best practice, but this is development env.

> **UPDATE**: I think I have found the issue. The problem is that I'm trying to use root user to login the remote machine. This IS NOT supported, even with public key authentication. The script has to be executed with the user `icinga`
>
> 2nd Update: I got it works. The issue was keys authentication, the fact that icinga uses the user icinga to execute the command (even when using by_ssh_logname attribute) and the addition of `vars.by_ssh_options = "StrictHostKeyChecking no"`

Comment: It is allowed to answer your own question if you found a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the issues, there were few of them in my case.

1. Icinga used `icinga` user to login through SSH, even when I used `-l root`. So, to install ssh keys I had to execute `ssh-copy-id icinga@HOST` under `root` user (Icinga shell is set to /sbin/nologin)
2. I then copied the private key (again, of the root user) to icinga folder so it is accessible for the application, and changed the ownership of the file
3. Next, I tried to login using `icinga` user to the remote machine `sudo -u icinga ssh icinga@HOST -i id_rsa`
4. If step 3 fails, you need to figure it before you continue. Next thing I did was adding `StrictHostKeyChecking no` to the module  options.

Voila, this works now.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that the used rsa key files wasn't owned by the "nagios" user:

```
-rw------- 1 nagios nagios 3.2K Nov 30 14:43 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 nagios nagios  766 Nov 30 14:42 id_rsa.pub
```